# MVC Foolproof Validation with ASP.NET MVC WEB API project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, foolproof-validation

It seems Foolproof Validation does not work with WEB API:

```
// POST api/values
public void Post(MyModel model)
{
}    

public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Condition { get; set; }
    [RequiredIfFalse("Condition")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Fiddler:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:3858
Content-Length: 24


{Id: 1, Condition: true}
```

Response:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The method or operation is not implemented.","ExceptionType"
```

The same code works fine with classic MVC 4 temaplate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it wouldn't...

From a quick look at the source code [here](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/94877#1510399) the `FoolproofValidator` is tied to the System.Web.Mvc namespace by inheritting from `System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelValidator` so this library is not going to work for WebApi.

There is a [`DataAnnotationsModelValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.validation.validators.dataannotationsmodelvalidator%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for `System.Web.Http` so it might be able to be ported across but I cannot see a branch or version on the project site that has done that yet.